# Delete my old inet address

Tags: networking

I've been trying to renew my IPv4 for wlan0 and I can't seem to shake the same ip I've had for many months, I've tried these

```
 dhclient -r wlan0

 dhclient -v wlan0

 nmcli con down id wifiman

 nmcli con up id wifiman

 rm riv /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient*
```

I've also tried deleting the address directly with

```
 ip address del 192.168.X.XXX dev wlan0
```

There has to be some sort of work around for a new IP address right ?

Comment: Why do you want a new IP address on a LAN? You can set a static ip for your machine and then change it as you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, the "old" IP Address is being reassigned back to you because the MAC Address is recognized and has not changed. I've had the best results getting a new IP Address by changing (spoofing) the MAC Address.

Assuming you can change it, a couple of methods should work...

1. Use the MAC Address from a device you are no longer using (and haven't used for a long time).
2. Replace one or more bytes (or all bytes) with random bytes. For example:
   replace `00-01-02-FD-FE-FF` with `99-01-44-FD-FE-FF`.
3. Treat the MAC Address as a number and increment it. For example:
   replace `FD-FE-00-01-02-FF` with `FD-FE-00-01-02-00` or `FD-FE-00-01-03-00`
4. Swap any 2 or 3 bytes. For example:
   replace `00-01-02-FD-FE-FF` with `01-00-02-FD-FE-FF` or `02-01-00-FD-FE-FF`
5. Rotate the bytes one or more positions. For example:
   replace `00-01-02-FD-FE-FF` with `FF-00-01-02-FD-FE` OR `01-02-FD-FE-FF-00`

The MAC Address has to be unique for each/all devices in your local network (not Globally unique). Method 1 is probably the most fool-proof at avoiding a conflict, but the chance you will duplicate an existing local MAC Address is very low.

If you do create a conflict, just try again. My favorite is method 5 (or 4) because it's easier to revert back to your original MAC Address if you ever need/want to.

Answer (score 5):

DHCP servers generally keep a cache of MAC Address to IP address mappings, so that they can reassign the same IP address to a returning client.

What is happening is that you're releasing the IP address lease, then asking the DHCP server for an IP address. The server knows that it gave you 192.168.X.XXX before (you have the same MAC address), so it reissues the address.

This sounds like an XY problem - what are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yup.  Of course, you could spoof the MAC address then you could get a new one ...

Answer (score 4):

I am fairly confident that the persistent IP address is a result of the software built in to the router. Based on its previous leases and the MAC address of the devices connecting to it, it once again gives the exact same address to the exact same devices.

If you have administrative privileges for the router, you could change the range of addresses used for DHCP. If, for example, the range for DHCP is now 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.51 (50 addresses), change it to 192.168.1.101 to 192.168.1.150. Upon reboot, you will certainly get a different IP address.

You could also set a static IP address in Network Manager, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdBcr.jpg Of course, be certain to select an address outside the DHCP pool in the router. In this way, you can use, and change at any time, the address you specify.